# Maximal Ideals in the ring k[x1,...,xn ]

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Hi. From one of the forms of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz we know that all the maximal ideals in a polynomial ring $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field, are of the form $(x_1 - a_1, \dots , x_n - a_n)$. So that any maximal ideal in this case is generated by polynomials $g_j \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ for $j = 1, \dots , n$, where $g_j$ only depends on the variable $x_j$ (Obviously by taking $g_j = x_j - a_j$). Now, I'm interested in the case of a polynomial ring $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ where $k$ is an arbitrary field (i.e., I can't make use of the Nullstellensatz). I suppose this may no longer be the case, i.e., I don't expect any maximal ideal to be generated by n polynomials, each of them only dependent on one of the variables $x_j$, but my question is if maybe the maximal ideals can be generated by polynomials $g_j$ that only depend on the first $j$ variables $x_1, \dots , x_j$? If so, does anybody know how to prove this or can anyone suggest me some references that may help me?. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The stronger version of the Nullstellensatz states that a maximal
ideal $I$ of $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is the kernel of a $k$-homomorphism
from $R$ to $L$ where $L/k$ is a finite extension. Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$
be the images of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ under such a homomorphism.
Then $a_1$ has a minimal polynomial $m_1$ over $k$. Let
$f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=m_1(x_1)$. Then $f_1\in I$

Now $a_2$ has a minimal polynomial $m_2$
over $k(a_1)$. We can write the coefficients of $m_2$ as polynomials
in $a_1$ over $k$. Doing this, and replacing $a_1$ by $x_1$ and the free
variable by $x_2$ gives a polynomial $f_2$ in $x_1$ and $x_2$. Also $f_2\in I$.

Keep going. We get a sequence of polynomials $f_i$ in $x_1,\ldots,x_i$
and it's not hard to prove these generate $I$.

Comment: Isn't the $g_1(x_1)$ you wrote in the first step actually $m_1(x_1)$?

Comment: Robin, where can I find that version of the Nullstellensatz?

Comment: This is equivalent to the form given in Lang (and reproduced at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15226/elementary-interesting-proofs-of-the-nullstellensatz/15230#15230 ).  

Comment: It is an easy exercise to prove Robin's statement from that one.

Answer (score 6):

In response to the OP's request for an explicit reference:

see Theorems 128 and 130 on pages 82-83 of

[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/integral.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Pete, I couldn't find the part that says the extension is finite.

Comment: That's Theorem 128c).

Comment: What would the reference be for your updated notes?