# When spreading out a scheme, does the choice of max ideal matter?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, finite-fields, schemes

I'm looking at Serre's paper [*How to use Finite Fields for Problems Concerning Infinite Fields*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.0517.pdf). Specifically I'm trying to use the techniques in the proof of Theorem 1.2 to write out the details of the proof of Theorem 3.1, but I'll try to ask a more general question.

Here's how I currently understand *spreading out* a scheme: If you have a scheme $X$ of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$, you can replace it by a scheme over some finite extension of the prime subring of $k$, either $\mathbf{Z}$ or $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$. Since $X$ is defined by a finite amount of data (by finitely many polynomials in the case $X$ is a variety) you can simply adjoin this data (the coefficients of the polynomials) to the prime subring of $k$. Call this extension of the prime subring $\Lambda$, and notice that $X$ is still defined over $\Lambda$. You can also adjoin any other finite amount of data from $k$ to the subring too, for example the coefficients of a polynomial map $X \to X$, so it will be preserved when you define $X$ over $\Lambda$. Furthermore you can take a max ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $\Lambda$, and $X$ will be defined over the quotient $\Lambda/\mathfrak{m}\,,$ [which will be a finite field](https://mathoverflow.net/q/57515/64073). And then you can even take the algebraic closure of $\Lambda/\mathfrak{m}$ if you'd like; I suppose it depends on what you need.

In the proof of Theorem 1.2, I'm troubled that Serre says you can choose *any* max ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Does it really not matter which one? The whole idea behind the proof is that if there is a counterexample over $k$ then it will descend to a counterexample over $\Lambda/\mathfrak{m}$, but don't we have to worry about $\mathfrak{m}$ containing too much of the data that we appended in $\Lambda$? Specifically in the proof of Theorem 1.2 in that paper, what if $\mathfrak{m}$ contains all the coefficients of the $Q_{g,i}$'s that we need to say that the action *doesn't* have a fixed point? And then Serre additionally takes the algebraic closure of $\Lambda/\mathfrak{m}$, and I don't see what's gained by this.

Comment: The scheme-theoretic argument is that if $\mathcal X \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ is a nice family (e.g. flat with geometrically integral fibres, although it might work with much weaker hypotheses) where $R$ is a domain of finite type over $\mathbb Z$, then the locus in $\operatorname{Spec} R$ where a map $f \colon \mathcal X \to \mathcal X$ of $R$-schemes is not injective (resp. not surjective) is constructible. Thus, if it contains all closed points, it must be all of $\operatorname{Spec} R$.

Comment: In a more model-theoretic language, the idea is indeed that if there exists a counterexample in characteristic $0$, then there also exists one in large positive characteristic. This is an example of a *compactness* argument in model theory.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thanks! Yeah, I really like the model-theoretic perspective on this proof technique: it hides most of the heavy lifting in the compactness theorem and proving that the theory of algebraically closed fields of a fixed characteristic is complete. I think I'm being a tad paranoid about the details of unpacking those ideas into purely a algebraic-geometry and commutative-algebra language, hence this question :)